# Nodejs Express routing with parameters from database

Tags: express

I am building an app where people can ask questions on certain discussions.
Users are allowed to make new discussions and when you click on a discussion you can ask a question about that certain discussion.

Now I want the url to look something like this /questions/*discussionid from the database*

Every discussion saved in the database has its own id.

Here is my route

routes/questions.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) { 
 var id = req.params.id;

 Dsc.findById(id, function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
    res.render('questions.ejs', {docs: doc});
});
});
 module.exports = router;
```

I have this in my server.js file

```
var DscSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 dsc: String,
 discussionID: String
});

var Dsc = mongoose.model('Discussion', DscSchema);
```

I get the error Dsc is not defined

discussions is the name of the document where I store all the discussions in mongodb

so for example on the discussion page I add a new discussion I then click on it I go to page /questions/1 for a new discussion i then go to /questions/2.

Comment: Just change `/:id` to `/questions/:id` and it will fix url

Comment: how do I link the discussion to the right questions url? because I have this in my link atm  <a href='/questions'>

Comment: I thinks it's more like question about how to generate template in ejs

Comment: I just want for every discussion a page with a link to that discussion

Comment: So I can save & show questions only for that discussion

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the Mongoose Model as follows...

```
var Dsc = mongoose.model('Discussion', DscSchema);
module.exports = Dsc;
```

And import the same in routes/questions.js as....

```
var Dsc= require("<PATH_TO_SCHEMA>");
```

This will fix the "Dsc is not defined" error